# I'm not sure why the dealer isnt hitting

Tags: c#, blackjack

This is the card I'm working with and I'm very confused to why the dealer isn't hitting when instructed to. I've rearranged my code tried different methods but it still doesn't seem to be working. If someone can help me solve this C# script I'd be very thankful.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MainClass 
{
    public static int PlayerTotal;
    public static int DealerTotal;

    static Random random = new Random();

    public static List<int> cards = new List<int>();
    public static List<int> hand = new List<int>();
    public static List<int> DealerHand = new List<int>();

    public static bool GameOver = false;

    public static void Main (string[] args) 
    {
        // Players hand gets created
        for (int i = 2; i <= 11; i++) 
        {
            cards.Add(i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            int index = random.Next(cards.Count);
            hand.Add(cards[index]);
        }

        foreach (int a in hand)  
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", a);
            PlayerTotal = PlayerTotal + a;

            if(PlayerTotal == 22 || PlayerTotal == 21) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You won!");
                GameOver = true;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Your hand total is " + PlayerTotal);

        // Dealer hand being created
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
        {
            int index = random.Next(cards.Count);
            DealerHand.Add(cards[index]);
        }

        foreach(int a in DealerHand) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", a);
            DealerTotal =  DealerTotal + a;

            if(DealerTotal == 22 || DealerTotal == 21) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The dealer won!");
                GameOver = true;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The dealer hand total is " + DealerTotal);

        // Player choice to hit or stay
        while (PlayerTotal < 21 && GameOver == false) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to hit or stand? h/s");
            string choice = Console.ReadLine();

            if (choice == "h")
            {
                PlayerHit();
            } 
            else if (choice == "s")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You stood");
            }
        }

        while (DealerTotal < 21 && GameOver == false ) 
        {
            if(DealerTotal <= 16) 
            {
                DealerHit();
            } 
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The dealer stood");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void PlayerHit() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) 
        {
            int index = random.Next(cards.Count);
            int hitCard = cards[index];
            hand.Add(hitCard);

            PlayerTotal = PlayerTotal + hitCard;
            Console.WriteLine("You got a " + hitCard);
            Console.WriteLine("Your new total is " + PlayerTotal);

            if(PlayerTotal > 21)  
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You lost!");
                GameOver = true;
            } 
            else if (PlayerTotal == 21) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You won!");
                GameOver = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void DealerHit()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            int index = random.Next(cards.Count);
            int DealerHitCard = cards[index];
            DealerHand.Add(DealerHitCard);

            DealerTotal = DealerTotal + DealerHitCard;
            int DealerHitCardNew = DealerHitCard;

            Console.WriteLine("The dealer got a " + DealerHitCardNew);
            Console.WriteLine("The dealers total is now " + DealerTotal);

            if (DealerTotal > 21)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You Won!");
                GameOver = true;
            } 
            else if (DealerTotal == 21)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You Lost!");
                GameOver = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated. My school has set us homework that we have to create a sort of application, and i thought this would be fun to make.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you describe exactly how to reproduce the problem with the code you've posted? If you could reduce it to a minimal example, format it more readably (Visual Studio will do that for you) and explain to us what happened when you debugged through the code, that would really help to make your question useful.

Comment: **[Using the free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** to debug your code is easier than you think.

Comment: The problem is i don't know what part of this code is causing this problem, i'm new to c# and the way it works so this is confusing to why it isn't working. Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm not running into any errors, it's just not working the way i want it too.

Comment: Thats what the debugger and debugging is for - watch and check your code and variables as it executes.  We *did* understand the post

Answer (score 0):

This line here:

```
while(PlayerTotal < 21 && GameOver == false) {
```

That will only be true if you bust or get 21.  If you stand, you will never exit this loop.  Add a break to the stand option:

```
        } else if(choice == "s"){
            Console.WriteLine("You stood");
            break;
        }
```

Unfortunately, you have the same issue in the following loop:

```
while(DealerTotal < 21 && GameOver == false ) {
```

Add a `break` to the correct block to exit the loop when the dealer stands.  Finally, you will need to add winning/losing logic after both the player and the dealer have stood.